# Binding XAML grid to an array

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a setup working where i can bind my grid.row properties of a rectangle to an integer in a class in the source behind, but I would really like to be able to use array's of integers instead of integers. The code I had worked when gridColumn was a simple integer but not when it is put into an array like so:

C# code:

```
namespace WPFTestingApplication
{
    public static class GridProperties
    {
        public static int[] gridColumn = { 1, 0 };
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestingApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestingApplication"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Name="Rect" Grid.Column="{Binding Source={x:Static
        local:GridProperties.gridColumn[0]}}" Fill="DarkGray" Margin="5" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in the VS output window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Grid.Column="{Binding [0], Source={x:Static Member=local:GridProperties.gridColumn}}"
```

I hope this will help.